# Using $.post, $.ajax or AJAX properly in CodeIgniter to call a PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm not so much of a framework fan but I have been made to use it because I am working on a project that others may edit later.

I am using the `CodeIgniter` framework (I'm kinda new on it).

I am using `jquery` `$.post(url, function() {})` to asynchronously call a login parser that is in the root directory under a folder called `php-parser` I realized this folder does not make use of any of the `CodeIgniter's` ready made class. I decided to move the folder `php-parser` into `application/libraries` but when I tried to use `jQuery` to call it referencing the full path `/application/libraries/php-parser/the-script.php`, it return a `403 forbidden error`

What do you think I can do? Some people said I could make the script a controller but here is what is going on, It's a popup modal login page. From any page if you click the login / register button, the modal pops up, how can I make a controller and a model for that (if I'm to follow that procedure).

**Added:** I put the modal content at the end of the footer which is included on all pages, how do I get to create a controller for that kind of modal? Any help!

Comment: it sounds like you need to read more about the framework if you plan on using it. for starters, maybe this documentation on controllers in codeigniter: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html it explains the process of making a simple hello world method, you can expand on this to make a controller function the way you need your login parser to

Comment: Voting me down does not solve my problem @skrilled I have read it and I'm still reading it but I don't seem to get a work around working with modals that's why I'm here.

Comment: If you had truly read the documentation, even try following it's tutorials step by step, you would know how to print "Hello World" on a screen. What comes after that is printing whatever you want. Print a JSON string of {"loggedIn":true}.

Comment: in nutshell [this MVC is very advanced concept] view-what client see model interact with DB controller validations/model are loaded

Comment: Oh mehn u r getting on my nerve @skrilled are you interviewing me on whether I have read the documentation or not? If you care to know I have a full site running on CodeIgniter. The login I am trying to do here is different from any other I have done. The modal popup is just beneath the footer which is loaded on every page. When login is click, the footer pops up from there how do I create a controller for that!

Comment: @skrilled New codeigniter doc's location here for both version http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need to put your file inside the libraries folder(if the class is separate from codeigniter or is shared among many controllers, if **not** a Model would suffice), then create a controller for it.

```
class Ajax_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public $statusCode = 200;

    public $response = array();

    public function __construct()
    { 
       parent::__construct();

       if(!$this->is_ajax_request()){
          return; // direct access not allowed
       }

       $this->response = array(
           'error' => false,
           'text'  => "",
           'fields' => array()
       );
    }

    public function sendResponse()
    {
        return $this->output
                    ->set_status_header($this->statusCode)
                    ->set_content_type('application/json')
                    ->set_output(json_encode($this->response));
    }
}
class Auth extends Ajax_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('php-parser/script', 'authentication');
    }

    public function login()
    {

        if(!$this->form_validation->run()){
            $this->response = array(
               'error' => true,
               'text'  => "The form has some errors",
               'fields' => array(
                   'username' => form_error('username'),
                   'password' => form_error('password')
               )
           );
           return $this->sendResponse();
        }

        $username= $this->input->post('username');
        $password= $this->input->post('password');

        if(!$this->authentication->login($username, $password)){
            $this->response = array(
                'error' => true,
                'text'  => "incorrect username/password combination",
                'fields' => array() 
            );
            $this->statusCode = 401;
            return $this->sendResponse();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: There are two classes here, which is the one to be in the `library` folder and which should be the controller?

Comment: Both of those are Controllers(one inherits from the other, keeping the code DRY). You would need to put "php-parser/script" inside the libraries folder(if independent from codeigniter, otherwise you would just put that logic into a model).  @Quentin has given you some great advice

Answer (score 6):

When dealing with MVC (at least the way you are using it) you have three parts:

- The Model - in this case this is the code which interacts with your database.
- The View - the code which formats the data you are sending back to the browser
- The Controller - the code which connects the two together and might have some business logic in it.

You also have some routing code which maps a URL onto the right controller for that URL.

---

Browsers (and other clients) only interact with web servers through URLs.

So you absolutely need to have a Controller set up to handle the request from the browser.

---

If you are doing this the quick and dirty way, then your controller will just get the username and password from the POST request, check it against the database with the model, and then squirt either "Success!" or "Fail!" into the view (which is probably best written as something that returns JSON formatted back to the browser).

---

If you are being [sensibly robust about this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) then the view will have logic something along the lines of:

Does the browser explicitly include JSON in the accept header?

If so, send back a bit of JSON saying "success" or "failure" (or true / false, or whatever makes sense for you).

Does it not? Then either return a "Sorry, you failed to login!" HTML document or a redirect back to the page they came from (so it will reload in the logged in state).

That way, if the JavaScript fails [for any reason](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html), the plain HTML form which was progressively enhanced with the Ajax JavaScript will still function. (NB: You have to write it that way!).

jQuery will automatically include a JSON friendly Accept header if you say `dataType: "json"` in the Ajax options.

Comment: means validations should me done on both side putting less amount of load on server is that above means

Comment: The login is not a full page that can have the conventional controllers and model that others do (to the best of my understanding). The modal login form is just beneath the `</footer>` which is loaded on every page so that on whichever page you are you can click on login and this will pop up, how do i make the `login` button` on that modal call a `PHP` script or make use of a controller and a model?

Comment: "the conventional controllers and model that others do" — Wrong. I explained that in the answer. The view is responsible for determining how the data sent to the browser is formatted. If you don't want a complete HTML document, then the view shouldn't send one. The model and controller are irrelevant (because they are for getting the data, organising it and passing it to the view, and the data for a successful login isn't going to change between a full HTML page and a lump of JSON).

Comment: "how do i make the login button` on that modal call a PHP script" — You put it in a form then submit the form as normal. Then, if you don't want to load an entire new page, you progressively enhance it with JavaScript (to perform Ajax). There are plenty of Ajax tutorials out there, writing a new one is out of scope for a SO answer, let alone a comment.

Comment: Okay good here is the point from my question. I may not be too good at asking questions maybe that's why you did not get me. If that button is click it calls a php script where? A controller, a model? a library file or my own `php-parser` folder in the root directory that will not be able to make use of the codeigniter's classes?

Comment: The button makes the browser make an HTTP request (either by submitting a form or running JavaScript that performs Ajax). The HTTP request is to a URL. The URL is examined by CodeIgniter's routing code. The routing code triggers a Controller. Again, that is already in the answer.

Comment: @Quentin i didn't get you on that point conventional controller point could you explain in more simple way

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshiVersion1.0 — No, my last comment spelled it out in the most basic terms I can come up with.

Comment: @Quentin i am basically asking abt this ""the conventional controllers and model that others do" — Wrong."

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshiVersion1.0 — That's a quote from Prodigy. My response to it was quite detailed. Again, I don't see how they can be simplified.